# Manually register spring integration flow and multiple subflows

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

After upgrading to spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE the application start fails with:

Field integrationFlow in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder required a single bean, but 2 were found:...

I'm trying to manually register the flows using IntegrationFlowContext class.

```
@Component
public class FlowCreator{

  @Autowired
  private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

  @Autowired
  private FlowExample flowExample;


  @PostConstruct
  public void registerIntegrationFlows() {

    flowContext.registration(flowExample.integrationFlow1())
    .id("integrationFlow1")
    .register();

    flowContext.registration(flowExample.integrationFlow2())
    .id("integrationFlow2")
    .register();
}

@Component
public class FlowExample {

  public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow1() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("input")
        .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, routeMessages()) //
        .get();
  }

  private Consumer<RouterSpec<Class<?>, MethodInvokingRouter>> routeMessages() {
    return m -> m //
        .subFlowMapping(Boolean.class, subFlow1()) 
        .subFlowMapping(Integer.class, subFlow2())
        .defaultOutputChannel("discardChannel");
  }

  private IntegrationFlow subFlow1() {
    return sf -> sf.channel("Channel1");
  }

  private IntegrationFlow subFlow2() {
    return sf -> sf.channel("Channel2");
  }

  public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow2() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("input")
        .channel("channel3")
        .get();
  }
}
```

Now I get the following error:

Field integrationFlow in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder required a single bean, but 2 were found:

- integrationFlow1.subFlow#0: defined in null
- integrationFlow1.subFlow#1: defined in null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in Spring Cloud Stream `2.1.1`: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/794c75f5364b51d7ec89335b08bfaca0f6d4d139#diff-737803e2a91ac21a17baf06ff7b4cbac.

Consider to upgrade to `Fishtown SR3`, or even `Germantown GA`: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#learn